# VB: SQL update does not seem to update the record

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have a checkbox placed in a gridview that when ticked I need it to update the record from 0 to 1. I have got the below code behind and its just not updating any records. there are no errors thrown so I am not sure what its doing...

here is the code behind.

```vb
   Protected Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    For Each gvRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows 'itterate tru all rows
        Dim chkBox As CheckBox = CType(gvRow.FindControl("cbSelect"), CheckBox) 'find the checkBox inside GridView

        Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection("Data Source=XXXXXXX\XXXXX;Initial Catalog=Support_Metrics;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=reportserver;Password=XXXXXXXX")
        Dim sqlComm As New SqlCommand("update BusinessSignups set contacted=@cbSelect where ID='" & gvRow.Cells(0).Text & "'", sqlcon) 'this is an insert example, you can do update you can get the current gridView row id using gvRow.Cells(0).Text
        'Dim sqlComm As New SqlCommand("insert into BusinessSignups (contacted) values (@cbSelect)", sqlcon) 'this is an insert example, you can do update you can get the current gridView row id using gvRow.Cells(0).Text
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cbSelect", chkBox.Checked) 'passing the @cbSelect parameter to the command
        'sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int)
        Using (sqlcon)
            sqlcon.Open() 'open connection
            sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery() 'execute the command
        End Using
    Next
End Sub
```

Here is some of the ASPX code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="BusinessSignUps" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="ID">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="False" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelect" runat="server" Checked="false" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" Visible="true" />
.....
```

Where am I going wrong? Please go easy this is all super new for me.

Comment: Did you check gvRow.Cells(0).Text and chkBox.Checked values? An advice: use parameters too for gvRow.Cells(0).Text.

Comment: If possible, then debug and check what exact SQL query is sent to the server - then try that SQL directly yourself and see the result

Answer (score 0):

One thing I often forget to do is `commit;` after my sql updates or inserts. Does that help or does the SqlConnection auto-commit?

Comment: No need if you aren't using transacctions.

Comment: Yeah. Another "lets throw stuff uip and hope I get upvotes" answer.

Comment: Thanks Phx. TomTom: It's worth a try since there were no other answers and that's the behaviour the site encourages.